# What windows tooling to create Python bdist_msi package?

Tags: python, windows-installer

Can someone point me at a good introduction to creating a Windows MSI installer for a Python package?  The function that I need is:

1. Raise the Windows auth level
2. Install as normal using `pip...`
3. Now run additional script to move some files where a standard user cannot put them
4. Reverse this on uninstall.

It looks like a `bdist_msi` is the simplest way to achieve this but the internet seems somewhat lacking on a good example showing what Windows tooling I need to add to enable `python setup.py bdist_msi` to do its stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: See `pyinstaller` or `py2exe`, it is like `py2deb`, we're all familiar with this

Comment: Not sure that these are quite what I want.  My use case is that I am installing a Python package (it is a Git extension) but cannot add Git-ish man/html files into the Git system as they sit in directories that are "hard to write to".  The package is not at all standalone and ideally I really do just want to run "pip install <my-package>" thenn use the installer to copy them elsewhere too.
It is a bit of a hotch-potch but it seems to be the only way to nicely integrate my tool with the existing Git help framework.

Comment: You can try to install it with administrator privileges

Comment: @Johnny That would probably work but it requires more knowledge that the users might have.   An MSI would be better as it forces the user to "do the right thing" instead of hoping that they do and generating complaints if they don't.